# Is there a term for making a statement while denying you're making said statement? e.g. "I'm not saying your mom... but"

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Is there a particular term for making a statement while explicitly denying ownership of the statement? Sometimes this is followed up by an appeal to another party to validate the truth of the statement. We've probably heard this a lot recently. For example:

"I'm not saying she's a crook..."

Comment: It's a form of innuendo.

Comment: It's perhaps a form of paralipsis?

Comment: Sounds like apophasis to me, also known as praeteritio or occupatio. It's a figure of speech which "asserts or emphasizes something by pointedly seeming to pass over, ignore, or deny it" (Robert A. Harris, "A Handbook of Rhetorical Devices").  As Harris points out, the figure has both legitimate and illegitimate uses.